# How to get next date from putting the any value in Java

Tags: java

I want to get next date by putting the any value.
like Today is 10/07/2018 when i give input 10 means I have need next date 20/07/2018.

Comment: Great! What did you try to solve this problem? Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Only a few steps are required :

- take user input
- take today's date (using [`Modern Java time API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html))
- add to the date the number of days of the input

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    LocalDate nextDate = nextDate(sc.nextInt());
}

private static LocalDate nextDate(int daysToAdd){
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    today = today.plusDays(daysToAdd);
    return today;
}

// can be inline in :
// return LocalDate.now().plusDays(int daysToAdd);
```

[***`Workable Demo`***](https://ideone.com/h7SJub)

Comment: Using `Scanner` instead of taking the number of days as a parameter prevents this method from being reusable.